# SWIG typemap for a function that returns various types

Tags: c++, lua, swig

**EDITED:**

I'm trying to create a simple getter function based on variable name used in Lua.

For example, it can be used like the following in Lua.

```
num = 123
str = "hello"
print(my.getValue("num")); --> result: 123
print(my.getValue("str")); --> result: hello
```

And this is `myBindings.h` file

```
static void getValue(const char *name, lua_State *L)
{
    lua_getglobal(L, name);
    switch (lua_type(L, -1))
    {
        case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
            //return boolean
            break;
        case LUA_TNUMBER:
            //return number
            break;
        case LUA_TSTRING:
            //return string
            break;
        case LUA_TTABLE:
            //return table
            break;
        default:
            //return nil
            break;
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

And this is `myBindings.i` file.

```
%module my
%{
    #include "myBindings.h"
%}

%include <stl.i>
%include <std_except.i>
%include <exception.i>
%include <typemaps.i>

%typemap(default) (lua_State *L) 
{
    $1 = L;
}

%include "myBindings.h"
```

How do I create a SWIG typemap so `getValue` function returns various types in Lua?

Comment: Are you sure about `void **p`?  Because `*$2` in `static_cast<int>(*$2)` will only be dereferenced once, resulting in `void *` which is then cast to `int`.  If `void **` is correct, you want `*static_cast<int*>(*$2)`.

Comment: “Here's my code that doesn't work”  Your code is not valid C++ and does nothing by default.  You need to provide a function `getVar` to be wrapped as well.

Comment: I edited my question since my previous approach using  `void**` might be completely wrong.

Comment: I updated my answer with, what I think is the desired behaviour.

Comment: You removed the checkmark from my answer, so I assume it is not satisfactory.  Please let me know where you find it to be lacking.

Comment: I removed the checkmark before you've edited your answer so I can give you a bounty for an updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one things wrong with the `getValue` function.  When you pop after the switch statement, you will pop whatever you pushed inside the switch statement.  I guess the intention is rather to pop the global whose type you query off the stack.  Therefore I just save the type in a local variable and pop the global immediately after.  For the sake of this example I'm pushing some dummy values.

```
static void getValue(const char *name, lua_State *L)
{
    lua_getglobal(L, name);
    switch (lua_type(L, -1))
    {
        case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
            lua_pushboolean(L, true);
            break;
        case LUA_TNUMBER:
            lua_pushnumber(L, 3.14);
            break;
        case LUA_TSTRING:
            lua_pushstring(L, "Hello world!");
            break;
        case LUA_TTABLE:
            lua_newtable(L);
            lua_pushstring(L, "value");
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "key");
            break;
        default:
            lua_pushnil(L);
            break;
    }
    // Before we can return we have to clean up the stack.  There is
    // currently the global "name" and the return value on the stack in this order
    //
    // 1. Return value
    // 2. "name"
    //
    // We cannot just lua_pop(L, 1) because that would remove the
    // return value which we of course want to keep.  To pop an
    // element at a specific position we have to use lua_remove.
    lua_remove(L, -2);
}
```

The interface file looks fine, but you have to notify SWIG that you pushed to the stack inside your C++ function and would like to return what you pushed.  Thus you have to increment `SWIG_arg` in an `argout` typemap.

```
%module my
%{
#include "myBindings.h"
%}

%typemap(default) (lua_State *L) {
    $1 = L;
}

%typemap(argout) (const char *name, lua_State *L) {
    ++SWIG_arg;
}

%include "myBindings.h"
```

Now we can check out the test script.  In the first case we are calling `getValue` with `"num"` where `num` has type number.  Thus we expect to obtain `3.14` as this is what is pushed by the C++ function.  In the second case we call with `"str"` where `str` is of type string.  Thus we should obtain `Hello world!`.

```lua
local my = require("my")

num = 123
str = "hello"
print(my.getValue("num"))
print(my.getValue("str"))
```

Let's try it out!

```
$ swig -lua -c++ test.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.2/ -fPIC -shared test_wrap.cxx -o my.so -llua5.2
$ lua5.2 test.lua
3.14
Hello world!
```

## Old answer before the question was edited

The `in` typemap is wrong.  `numinputs = 0` tells SWIG that zero inputs are needed for a function with this signature.  That's not true, because `name` is passed as an argument.  However, increasing `numinputs = 1` forces you to check and convert the first argument yourself.  Better let SWIG handle that and remove this argument from the typemap altogether.

```
%typemap(in, numinputs = 0) (void **p) {
    $1 = nullptr;
}
```

The `argout` typemap doesn't make any sense whatsoever and is not even valid C++.  Even if you'd correct the invalid casts it would still be a huge type-unsafe memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your new answer. It works well except it crashes when I try to get a table variable: `case LUA_TTABLE: lua_pushvalue(L, -1); lua_pushnil(L); while (lua_next(L, -2) { if (lua_isboolean(L, -1)) lua_pushboolean(L, lua_toboolean(L, -1)); else if (lua_isnumber(L, -1)) lua_pushnumber(L, lua_tonumber(L, -1)); else if (lua_isstring(L, -1) lua_pushstring(L, lua_tostring(L, -1)); lua_pop(L, 1); } lua_pop(L, 1); break;`

Comment: @ZackLee The code you posted is not part of my answer, so I have no idea what the context is.

Comment: For example, `case LUA_TNUMBER: lua_pushnumber(L, lua_tonumber(L, -1)); break;` this allows me to return a number from a number variable. So I expect the function to return a table from a table variable but the above code crashes and I don't know why.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer doesn't work. I'm saying I failed to use your answer to do what I want. (due to my limited knowledge) I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @ZackLee I think you want to access the global `"name"` inside the switch statement which is no longer possible because I have popped it before the switch.  You can pop it after the switch but you have to be careful with the stack indices. See the updated answer.